# Halloween Magic

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, rebus

> Halloween is coming, and the little skeleton is learning a new magic trick.
>
> Find the hidden key and solve the hidden code in the image. The code is 4 digits.

[image: The image]

Hint 1:

> The right page hints at the key
>  The left page hints at the info
>  The key and info together leads to the final code.

Hint 2:

> What gets thrown away here, may be needed elsewhere.

<sub>*created by Abai, originally posted in MiAnGuan, a social and UGC puzzle App, on Halloween 2022.*</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 4 digit code you are looking for is

> 2734*3 = **8202**

Right page : credits to @Arturo Vial Arqueros for this part

> You can link the top row and the bottom row of the letter bricks as stated on the right page, and reverse them as shown by the first teeth of the skeleton to obtain 2734 x [brown trapeze]
>  [image]

Left page :

> We just need to figure what the brown trapeze (the last tooth) is worth. You can place the unused bricks to obtain a 3
>  [image]

Comment: Well done, green checked this, as it's the first *complete* answer, albeit could you please credit Arturo Vial Arqueros's answer for being the first one taking the most important step (and without help of any extra hints)? :D

Comment: @Pumbaa Of course :D did not know if I should have commented the last part or made a completely new answer

Comment: Ooooh, that IS clever. I hadn't noticed the trapezium in the last tooth. Well noted, Neil!

Answer (score 13):

The 4 number code we're looking for is:

> 2734

We can first focus on the book:

> We're looking for 7-segment numbers, and we should focus on the first and fourth layers of bricks in the wall.

If we turn our attention onto the wall:

> We can "fold" the layers of brick to make a composed picture with the first and fourth lines. It'll look like this:
>  [image]

The last thing we need to check are the teeth:

> The leftmost teeth have the same symbol as we composed on the wall, but reflected. We can also see that the rightmost teeth have a chain in the form of an X, just like the wall by the painted symbols. If we reflect the designs on the wall to match the location of the key and chains, we can clearly see the number 2734
>  [image]

Comment: The 4 digits is wrong. The deduction is all correct, but *incomplete*.